# Быстрый и легкий MVC фреймворк, аналог Ext js?

Tags: javascript, extjs, фреймворк

Какой фреймворк MVC по архитектуре близок к ext js, но компактный, быстрый?

То есть в ext js, мне нравится работать с контроллерами, классами, моделями, сторами, вьюшками с tpl шаблонизатором. А виджеты(встроенные таблицы, панели, окна) почти не использую.

Но Ext такой тормозной и весит больше мегабайта. Вот ищу аналогичные средства MVC, но быстрые, компактные? Есть какая нибудь связка  (react js + что то еще = MVC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле уже в стабильной бете находится новая версия - [Angular 2](https://angular.io/). Angular 1 стал постепенно уходить в тень после выхода React с новыми, важными идеями.

Многих недостатков первой версии больше нет, и новое API, использующее новый стандарт JS, гораздо более простое и понятное.

Добавлю, что Angular дает огромную функциональность, и позволяет расширять HTML собственными тегами - директивами, но он, сам по себе, не содержит готовых графических компонент. Но благодаря огромному сообществу, готовых решений огромное количество. Различные модули для Angular можно найти например здесь: ngmodules.org

Comment: `One framework` ... `to rule them all`.

Comment: @Other Ага. Все так.

Answer (score 1):

Angular - MVC фреймворк, можно использовать как аналог

Comment: Вот еще тут можно глянуть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560447/what-is-the-best-alternative-for-extjs